# Nuxt3 app crashes when navigating to the same route with different param where page has $fetch (or useFetch)

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have route like this:

`/projects/:name`

And page like this:

`/pages/projects/[name].vue`

Inside that file I have very basic struff with fetch:

```
<template>
    <div>{{ project.title }}</div>
</template>

<script setup>
    const { params } = useRoute();
    const server = useRuntimeConfig().public.projectServer;

    const project = await $fetch(server + "/api/project/" + params.name);
</script>
```

When I go from `/projects/list` to `/projects/project-a` page renders well, everything works. Then I go back and click on `/projects/project-b` and app crashes. The order of clicks doesn't matter. Every time first navigation is successful but the second = crash. If I go directly to any of this route from addres bar, the page renders ok.

In console, I get `[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of scheduler flush.` and errors like `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'parentNode')` and `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'subTree')`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, apparently the problem was with some breaking change after updating to Nuxt `3.7.1` from `3.6.x`. I had that code in `/projects/list.vue`:

```
<div @click="navigateTo(`/projects/${project.name}`)">
   <p>
      Clicking here is ok, navigation works.
   </p> 
   <nuxt-link :to="`/projects/${project.name}`">
      Clicking here causes crash in 3.7.1.
   </nuxt-link>
</div>
```